# Is OPC server allowed to use source timestamp in its logic?

Tags: timestamp, opc-ua

Or to put in other words -- is source timestamp used only for client reporting purposes?

The case I wonder about is -- a client A writes some variable with source timestamp set. And later client B writes the same variable with source timestamp older than the one from client A (for whatever reason).

Now -- is server allowed to reject the write from B because both source timestamps are not null and it is clear the chronological order is broken, or server is **not** allowed to do such a thing (i.e. server has to accept newer writes as they come)?

Comment: Most of the OPC UA Client do not allow to write Source or Server timestamp. The DataValue send with a Write only contains the Value Attribute

Comment: @CamilleG., this is odd, because how could server tell the source timestamp then? Only client can tell the source timestamp of the value. I use OPC UA .Net stack and it allows **client** to set source timestamp and (this is also odd) server timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, but like Camille said you'll likely only find support for writing anything other than a value in your own custom server.

There's no `StatusCode` that would make it clear to clients why the write failed, but you could supplement the returned StatusCode with information in the `DiagnosticInfo`, assuming the client requested one.

Comment: Thanks you, but there is misunderstanding -- I am not asking if it is technically possible (I could set values on random after all), I am asking how to understand specification. I.e. the server which rejects older values is valid, or the one that does not reject? Or this is completely up the server implementation, and behavior can vary (and this is valid).

Comment: I don't see anything in the specification that defines this behavior. I believe it's completely up to the implementation.